# How to deal with routes when Laravel installed in subfolder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two applications: frontend (vuejs) and backend (laravel).

Both of them are deployed to the same ip address, say, 10.10.10.10. 
However, laravel is deployed to 10.10.10.10/api.

I need to return from my api a url to some route. So I use route helped and it worked fine if laravel is deployed to another domain, but in case of /api it returns just "http://10.10.10.10/url-to-route" ignoring /api part.

As far as I know `APP_URL` in the .env file is used only in CLI.

So how can I force `route` helper to use the `APP_URL` variable? I mean, of course I can do something like `env('APP_URL') . '/' . route('someroute')` but this seems to be hacky. I guess it's a common task to deploy laravel to a subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know APP_URL in the .env file is used only in CLI.

Nope. The `route` helper uses `APP_URL`. Set it accordingly.

Comment: (and yes, I just tested this to be 100% certain)

Comment: No way! :) It works only in console (eg php artisan tinker). Here is the comment from config/app.php which uses APP_URL:  This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using the Artisan command line tool.